# Accessing multiple data sources with [[ ]] indexing in R

Tags: r, indexing

here is my code:

```
file.number <- c(1:29)
data <- setNames(lapply(paste0(file.number, ".csv"), read.csv), paste0(file.number, ".data"))
n <- c(1:3,10:15,21:26)
sw <- na.omit(data[[n]]$RT[data[[n]]$rep.sw=="sw"])
rep <-na.omit(data[[n]]$RT[data[[n]]$rep.sw=="rep"])
```

The problem is that 3rd line - if n = 1, it works, but if I include multiple numbers I get an error "recursive indexing fail." Is there a way I can access multiple indexes at once?

Thanks R Community! Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's likely because of the `[[` bracketing.    Try `data[n]` when you're indexing more than one element.  Furthermore, you'll probably need for example  `lapply(data[n], na.omit)` to get this to work.

Comment: I get a different error if I do that: "is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'." And when I run sw command it is nulled.

Comment: It's massive; it exceeds this text box limit by 148583 characters. Can I provide you with a subset or something?

Comment: Yeah, just copy and paste a few lines of about three list elements

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful:

target_location = c(3L, 5L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA), gap_side = structure(c(3L,3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "left", "right"), class = "factor"), response = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "['m']", "['z']"), class = "factor"), accuracy = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "correct", "wrong"), class = "factor"), rep.sw = structure(c(NA, 3L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "rep", "sw"), class = "factor"), RT = c(0.743383531109, 0.712899116566, NA, 0.775258792739,0.853063922899, NA)), .Names = c("trial_num", "target_color"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

It looks like `data` is a list of data frames. The list elements are named, e.g. `1.data`, `2.data`, etc. and each data frame has, among other things, columns named `RT` and `rep.sw`. So, like this:

```
## representative example???
df   <- data.frame(RT=1:100,rep.sw=sample(c("sw","rep"),100,replace=TRUE))
data <- setNames(lapply(1:29,function(i)df),paste0(1:29,".data"))
```

You seem to want to remove `NA`'s from the `RT` column of each data frame for rows where `res.sw=="sw"` (or `"rep"`).

If that is correct, then something like this should work:

```
sw  <- lapply(data[n],function(df) with(df,na.omit(RT[rep.sw=="sw"])))
rep <- lapply(data[n],function(df) with(df,na.omit(RT[rep.sw=="rep"])))
```

This code will pass the data frames identified in `n` to the function one at a time, and for each of those return the rows of column `RT` for which `rep.sw="sw"`, with `NA`'s omitted. The result will be a list of vectors.

I notice that most of the columns are imported as factors, which is probably a bad idea. You might want to import using:

```
data <- setNames(lapply(paste0(file.number, ".csv"), read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
                 paste0(file.number, ".data"))
```

Comment: You are sincerely amazing, if it wasn't for people like you and this community I would be completely lost. Thank you!